# Python CSV script

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to add a new column by copying col#3 and then append @hotmail to the new column

Here is the script, only problem is that it will not finish processing the input file, it only show 61409 rows in the output file, whereas in the input file there are 61438 rows.
Also, there is an error message (the input file does not have empty line at the end):
email = row[3]
IndexError: list index out of range

```
inFile = 'c:\\Python27\\scripts\\intake.csv'
outFile = 'c:\\Python27\\scripts\\final.csv'

with open(inFile, 'rb') as fp_in1, open(outFile, 'wb') as fp_out1:
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out1, delimiter=",")
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in1, delimiter=",")
    for col in reader:
        del col[6:]
        writer.writerow(col)
    headers = next(reader)
    writer.writerow(headers + ['email2'])
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 3:
            email = email.split('@', 1)[0] + '@hotmail.com'
        writer.writerow(row + [email])
```

Comment: Your error message seems to refer to a line which isn't in your code.  If you're getting an `IndexError` when you access `row[3]`, then simply add `print row` before the access and see what line is giving you trouble.  For the code you've posted, after you've finished the `for col in reader:` loop, you're at the end of the file, so I don't see how `next(reader)` or `for row in reader:` would work/do anything.

Comment: I agree with @DSM, you should post your actual code, or something that behaves the same way.

Comment: Are you using the code from your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324968/python-csv-copy-column ? If so, maybe you should have added to that question rather than start a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you edited the code you received in your earlier answer.

Change

```
email = email.split('@', 1)[0] + '@hotmail.com'
```

to

```
email = row[3].split('@', 1)[0] + '@hotmail.com'
```