# Python CSV - Combine, clean and to output emails in correct format

Tags: python, regex, email, csv

I am trying to take more than 1 file with information such as names, email addresses, and other. To take these files from CSV format and remove everything except the emails. Then output a new file with delimiter of semicolon all on same line.
The final format should look like:

```
someone@hotmail.com; someoneelse@gmail.com; someone3@university.edu
```

I must check the emails are in correct format of `alphanumeric@alphanumeric.3letters`.
I must remove all duplicates.
I must compare this list to another and remove the emails from 1 list that occur in the others.

The final format will be such that someone can copy and paste into Outlook the email recipient addresses.

I have looked at some video. Also here. I found: [python csv copy column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324968/python-csv-copy-column)

But I get an error when trying to write the new file.
I have `import csv and re`

Here is my code below:

```
def final_emails(email_list):
  with open(email_list) as csv_file:
    read_csv = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    write_csv = csv.writer(out_emails, delimiter=";")

    for row in read_csv:
        email = row[2]  # only take the emails (from column 3)
        if email != '':  # remove empties

            # remove the header, or anything that doesn't have a '@'
            # convert to lowercase and append to list
            emails.append(re.findall('\w*@\w*.\w{3}', email.lower()))
            write_csv.write([email])
  return emails


final_emails(list1)
final_emails(list2)


print(emails)
```

I have the print to check at bottom.
I added write to make new file, but this error
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

I'm still trying to learn. I do many things this time I didn't before, like csv and regular expression.
Please any assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `out_emails` as file handle with writable permissions before you can use it in `csv.writer`

`csv.writer` needs an object which has a `.write` property like file handles to be able to write to it. It seems like `out_emails` doesn't have a `.write` property.

Comment: My define for out_emails looks like this:  out_emails = r"\\path\to\file.csv"

Comment: `out_emails` has to be file handle, something like `out_emails = open(r"\\path\to\file.csv", 'w')`